# How to properly combine multiple Find&Replace WordVBA codes?

Tags: vba, ms-word, wildcard

I'm a transcriber. I work with very long documents and use Find & Replace quite a lot. So I've been trying to write an efficient Word VBA code that finds and replaces multiple, specific wildcard strings in three different ways:

- Replace with bold.
- Replace with italics.
- Replace with uppercase.

To be clear, the idea is that by pressing a single button/shortcut I can find/replace a list of specific **wildcard** strings with bold, italics, and capital letters respectively; three "batches" of strings, three different replacement operations.

Currently I have a "global" code that calls three (3) separate codes, each calling more codes. I assume this is far from ideal. It's enormous, takes a long time to execute, gets laggy, etc.

This is the "global" code:

```
See update below.
```

These are the three (3) subsequent codes:

```
See update below.
```

And the remaining codes are more or less like these two:

```
See update below.
```

I think that if I can at least combine the "lower" codes that might be a step forward. I've been searching for information on how to find/replace multiple strings in one operation, and yes, there are many examples, but they do not make use of wildcards and I can't seem to add the "MatchWildcards" part correctly (if that's the way to do it, I really don't know) or modify them so that they work.

Any suggestions? Any threads I've missed?

I'm just beginning to learn about VBA coding. I apologize if there are clear examples of this that I didn't see, or if it has already been asked/answered, or if I'm missing the obvious here. I'd appreciate any information whatsoever. I'm not asking for someone to write me the full code. I really want to learn.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: A couple of thoughts: (1) create a character style that has the characteristics you want and replace with that style rather than separate, and (2) create a subroutine to do the replace and put the things that change with different replaces as variables that get passed to the subroutine. References: https://gregmaxey.com/word_tip_pages/vba_basics.html and http://www.gmayor.com/replace_using_wildcards.htm and https://www.msofficeforums.com/word-vba/51906-word-macro-wildcard-issue.html.

Comment: Thank you for your response! The subroutine idea worked! I'll post the code in a few.

Answer (score 0):

Update:

Thanks to Charles Kenyon I was able to clean the codes to a point it solved every issue I had.

These are the updated codes for anyone interested:

```
Sub ERET_SetFormat_ES()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Call ERET_SetBold
Call ERET_SetItalic
Call ERET_SetCase
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Sub ERET_SetBold()
    SetBold ""      'INSERT WILDCARD STRING
    SetBold ""      'INSERT WILDCARD STRING
    SetBold ""      'INSERT WILDCARD STRING
End Sub

Sub SetBold(findText As String)
    selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    selection.Find.Replacement.Font.Bold = True
    With selection.Find
        .Text = findText
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = True
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchWildcards = True
    End With
    selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End Sub

Sub ERET_SetItalic()
    SetItalic ""      'INSERT WILDCARD STRING
    SetItalic ""      'INSERT WILDCARD STRING
    SetItalic ""      'INSERT WILDCARD STRING
End Sub

Sub SetItalic(findText As String)
    selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    selection.Find.Replacement.Font.Italic = True
    With selection.Find
        .Text = findText
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = True
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchWildcards = True
    End With
    selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End Sub

Sub ERET_SetCase()
    Call SetCase("")    'INSERT WILDCARD STRING
    Call SetCase("")    'INSERT WILDCARD STRING
    Call SetCase("")    'INSERT WILDCARD STRING
End Sub

Sub SetCase(pattern As String)
    selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With selection.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Text = pattern
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = True
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = True
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
        .Execute
        While .Found
            selection.range.Case = wdUpperCase
            selection.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
            .Execute
        Wend
    End With
End Sub
```